# PhpMyAdmin 3.5.6 gives HTTP Error 403 in Windows Server 2003 with IIS 6

Tags: iis, phpmyadmin

I have setup new server with following configuration.

Windows Server 2003 with IIS 6 / PHP 5.2.17 / MySQL 5.0.51a / PhpMyAdmin 3.5.6

PHP working fine as phpinfo is displaying fine in browser.
MySQL is installed properly.

But PhpMyAdmin 3.5.6 gives HTTP Error 403 when try to access it in browser by following way.

```
http://localhost/phpmyadmin356 
OR
http://192.168.11.22/phpmyadmin356
```

phpmyadmin356 folder is under inetput >> wwwroot.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

I went through this guide. http://dpotter.net/technical/2009/03/installing-phpmyadmin-on-windows-and-iis-60/

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Probably your permissions aren't set correctly for the phpmyadmin356 directory and/or files within that folder. You probably need, at a minimum, read permissions for `IUSR` and `IIS_USERS`.