# php my admin on iis7 error HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden

Tags: php, networking, web, phpmyadmin, iis-7.5

error while trying to run PHPMyAdmin on my local host with iis7
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

Comment: Please check if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21335147/phpmyadmin-3-5-6-gives-http-error-403-in-windows-server-2003-with-iis-6) helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is most likely caused by having no suitable Default Document set for the directory. In IIS Manager, go into the Default Document section and make sure "index.php" is listed.

If it's not, add it. If it is added, make sure it's not disabled. That should fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks! have been searching for this answer for days!

Answer (score 0):

There is no default file like index.php found. Try this instruction on how to install phpmyadmin on iis7: http://blog.pluralsight.com/install-phpmyadmin-on-iis7-and-server-2008